# herokuでfiled to detectエラー

Tags: node.js, go, heroku, grunt

以下のディレクトリ構成のGo+JSアプリをherokuにデプロイしようとしています。

Directory structure

```html
|-Godeps
|-main.go
|-Procfile
|-static
  |-Gruntfile.js
  |-bower_components
  |-app
  |-bower.json
  |-dist
  |-package.json
```

Buildpackはnode.jsとGoのものを使用するのでいかのように追加しました。

buildpacks

```html
1. https://github.com/jasonswett/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt-compass
2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go.git
```

しかし、下記のfailed to detectエラーというエラーで失敗してしまいます。

エラー

```html
-----> Multipack app detected
-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
 !     Push rejected, failed to detect
```

またbuildpacksの順番を入れ替えるとGoのbuildpackはdetectされますがnodejsの方は以下のエラーがでてしまいました。

エラー2

```html
-----> Multipack app detected
-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Go app detected
-----> Checking Godeps/Godeps.json file.
-----> Installing go1.4.2... done
-----> Running: godep go install -tags heroku ./...
-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
 !     Push rejected, failed to detect
```

このことからおそらくNodeJSのbuildpackに問題があると考えられますがそれが何かわかりません。解決方法を教えて下さい。よろしくおねがいします。

参考にしたURL:https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app#examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。

nodejsのbuildpackがclientとうディレクトリをnodejsのアプリとdetectする仕様になっていたので、staticをclientに変更したところデプロイに成功しました。